# Do I need PID gains for velocity_controllers?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, gazebo-ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to use `velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController`. In [ros_controllers](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers), the controllers `velocity_controllers/JointVelocityController` and `velocity_controllers/JointGroupVelocityController` are forward command controller. My understanding is that the controller doesn't need pid gains; but if I compile my code, I get these errors

```
[ERROR] [1653642231.819643360, 0.195000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /rrbot/gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/joint1
[ERROR] [1653642231.820926527, 0.195000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /rrbot/gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/joint2
```

I'm using Gazebo 9 and melodic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/401456/do-i-need-pid-gains-for-velocity_controllers?/) by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2022-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have not used a velocity_controller, but I think the answer to your title question is "No".

As far as I know, that situation is not really an ERROR, and the log level should be more like INFO.  #q293830 has more discussion of this.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on 2022-05-28**:
When I add `gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains`, the arms falls down but removing them, the arm doesn't fall down. Interesting. I'm not sure what Gazebo is doing with the pid gains so that velocity controller is not able to maintain the zero setpoint. But again, forward command controller doesn't need any internal controller to map its input.